# Google Drive MD5 checksum for files

Tags: md5, google-drive-api, checksum

I'm not a programmer, just a regular user of Google Drive. I want to see if the files are uploaded correctly. I go through a whole process in the OAuth 2.0 Playground that lists all files, shows the MD5 checksums but also lots of information per file. If I upload a new file it's hard to search for it and verify its md5 checksum.

Is there an easier way (through an app, maybe?) to show/list MD5 checksums for the uploaded files? I wonder why the Details pane doesn't have it, only lists the file size in bytes.

Comment: `I wonder why the Details pane doesn't have it, only lists the file size in bytes.` Because 99.99% of users don't have any use for a MD5 hash of an uploaded file.

Comment: How else would you know the uploaded file is not corrupted?

Comment: One way will be to upload the md5sum along with the file. This can be used by anyone downloading the file.

Comment: thanks, but I've already figured out a way to do it and I'm going to add it as a reply.

Comment: @ZoeyMertes Which means that for every 1 million users, 100 are going to be inconvenienced... and it seems likely that it's these very users whose time is worth the most and suffer the largest economic cost.  All because of the lack of foresight to at least provide a way to show this detail for those who want to see it.

Comment: _I wonder why the Details pane doesn't have it, only lists the file size in bytes.
>>Because 99.99% of users don't have any use for a MD5 hash of an uploaded file._  
Nobody has a use for an MD5 hash until they do.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**edit: NB these instructions have changed slightly for the v3 API**

I've figured out a quick way to get the MD5 checksums of the files uploaded and decided to share it here, too. Log into your Google Drive account, then:

Visit: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

Scroll down to the **Try it!** section.

Change "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0" from OFF to ON by clicking on it, then select:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly

and click Authorize.

Choose your account then click Accept.

Fill in the **fields** field with:

for v2 API:

> items(md5Checksum,originalFilename)

for v3 API:

open "Show standard parameters" in GUI to see **fields** than

> files(md5Checksum,originalFilename)

to only get a list of filenames and MD5 checksums.

Click **Execute** and you'll open a list with all the files uploaded to Google Drive and their MD5 checksums.

Comment: To get the current filename (instead of the original uploaded filename) use `items(md5Checksum,title,owners/emailAddress)`

Comment: Is this secure?  It sounds like we're allowing read/write access to our entire Drive.

Comment: Yes, it is secured via Oauth2.  Note in the answer above he says "and click Authorize".  That's three simple words, but behind it is a pretty complex credential check mechanism.  If it isn't your file and you don't have the credentials, you will get a 'not authorized' response unless the file owner has made the file public.

Comment: @ElliottB you are indeed giving Google read/write access to your Google Drive. imho, they probably already have that :-)

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2019. Only some minor changes in the UI. eg: The `fields` field can be located after clicking `Show standard parameters` link and the Try it section is located on the right side of the webpage.

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2020, with minor changes. 1) You no longer need to check a box, `Google 0Auth 2.0` is checked by default. 2) For v3 API, you no longer need to select "Show Standard Parameters"; `fields` is found at the bottom of the list without needing to click this link.

Comment: This is limited though to 100 items. Is there a way to increase the item number, or to "paginate" the result through subsequent queries?

Comment: What exactly does this md5 represent? The MD5 hash of the original file on my hard drive or the MD5 of the file stored in drive? I am asking because I have uploaded using "google backup and sync" and by default it uploads pictures in "high quality"... image dimensions are capped if they are too big and jpeg is re-compressed to "near identical" quality.

Answer (score 15):

## API instructions

Google Developers - OAuth 2.0 Playground:

- https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Step 1: Select & authorize APIs:

- Expand "Drive API v3".
- Enable "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly".
- Click "Authorize APIs".
- Click "Allow".

Step 2: Exchange authorization code for tokens:

- Click "Exchange authorization code for tokens".

Step 3: Configure request to API:

- Enter the "Request URI".
- Click "Send the request".

## Request URI instructions

### All files in folder

Get specific fields of files in a folder:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="folderId"+in+parents&fields=files(md5Checksum,+originalFilename)
//
```

Replace "folderId" with the folder ID.

You can use `&fields=files(*)` to get all of the file's fields.

### Single file

Get specific fields of a file:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId?fields=md5Checksum,+originalFilename
//
```

Replace "fileId" with the file ID.

You can use `&fields=*` to get all of the file's fields.

## Parsing the JSON response

- Open a JavaScript console.
- Save the object into a variable.
- Map the object.
- Copy the result.

### Code

```
var response = {
  "files": [
    {
      "md5Checksum": "0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661", 
      "originalFilename": "a.txt"
    }, 
    {
      "md5Checksum": "92eb5ffee6ae2fec3ad71c777531578f", 
      "originalFilename": "b.txt"
    }
  ]
};


var result = response.files.map(function (file) { return (file.md5Checksum + " *" + file.originalFilename); }).join("\r\n");

console.log(result);
copy(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is easy and trustable.

Answer (score 10):

Here are three additional, different ways to list md5 checksums.

1. Install [Google Skicka](https://github.com/google/skicka), a command line tool for Google Drive and run `skicka ls -ll /`
   Although the readme file says it's not an official google product it is hosted on google's github account, so I guess it can be trusted.
2. There is [a plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drive-checksum/mcljolpofjcpckhnncpojbahnikjlebf) that lists all files with their checksums in drive's spreadsheet.
3. Here's my [python3 script](https://gist.github.com/yaci/581062fd19713faffffe1668f37707c0) that I've created for myself. It's mostly copied from [google's official examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample). You'll need to obtain client_secret.json file and place it in the same directory with the script - [here's the instruction](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on: [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2583094/alex)'s above answer!

1. Click the link : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list
2. Click the **Try it now** link in the middle.

   ( An active window appears in the middle )
3. Scroll down the **left pane** in the **active window**.
4. Under **fields** section on the left pane, fill

   **files(md5Checksum,originalFilename)**
5. Now we will limit access scopes :

   (i) leave the **Google OAuth 2.0** selected & clear the box against **API key**.

   (ii) Expand **Show scopes** under **Google OAuth 2.0**

   (iii) Clear all the scopes but keep this one selected:

   ```
    **https: //www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly**
   ```
6. Now click **EXECUTE** in blue.

   (A new **Google Sign In Window** will open)
7. Use that window to **Sign in** with the **respective** google account & click **Allow** to permit the Google APIs Explorer access files in your google drive.

   It's done! A new window will open with the results in **lower right code pane**. It will 
   provide the **names** & **md5Checksums** for **all** the **files** in the **respective** google 
   drive account.
8. Click outside of the active window to close the window & close the **Google Drive 
   API** tab. Now you can sign out of the google account if you want!

Comment: All Thanks To Alex!

Answer (score 1):

For someone who does not want to use this regularly, the API solution requires quite a lot of work.
I used colab to compute the md5 sum or check a file:

In colab do:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

- Follow autentification steps.
- Be careful: You have full access to your google drive now, including deleting files.

  cd /content/drive/Shareddrives/... # or similar
- Compute md5 sum:

  !md5sum file
- Verify a file for which the folder contains the md5 file:

  !md5sum -c file.md5

Answer (score 0):

Combined with [XP1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412486/xp1) and [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2583094/alex) guides to work in my scenario, to list MD5 for private folders that shared with me

-includeItemsFromAllDrives
-includeTeamDriveItems
-supportsAllDrives
-supportsTeamDrives

**Request URI** in [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="folderID"+in+parents&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&includeTeamDriveItems=true&supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&fields=files(md5Checksum%2CoriginalFilename)
```