# Google Drive Checksum

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, drive

Is there a way for me to retrieve Checksums via the Drive API?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24421391/7759514) goes through doing it via the documentations "Try it" function, which has a horrible interface.

How can I do this via the .NET (C#) Google Drive APIs?
Or, how can I do it using my own post/get requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) since its a basic list files method.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DriveQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = {  DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = 10;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}

    }
}
```

edit this line:

```
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
```

To:

```
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, md5Checksum)";
```

The solution from the link above is correct, Try it function will help you familiarize yourself with each method and how the response and request is formed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting how to do it.